# Create a custom class for change fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I am trying to create a custom class to handle change fragment. However, I cannot get the fragment manager in order to execute change fragment. What I have tried is to extend the class to **FragmentActivity** and get the fragment manager by using **getSupportFragmentManager()**. However, it returns error with **Fragment manager not attached to host**

Any idea that I can get the correct fragment manager to execute changing fragment? should I extend to another class?

```
public class changefragment extends FragmentActivity{

     public void ChangeFragment(){


        Fragment f = new MyCustomFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,f);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit;

    }
}
```

Comment: When you call ChangeFragment() method?

Comment: @CôngHải I will call this method when the bottom navigation bar item is clicked